# How to create link to create a custom content type in Site Actions menu?

Tags: content-type, publishing-site, editing-menu, layouts

I am new in SP2010 and I want to ask if anyone knows how to do the following. I have made some new custom content types based in the Article page (Publishing page) and assigned new layouts to them. Is there a way to **include links to create directly these content types from the Site actions menu** instead of going to Site Actions->More options ->Publishing Pages and the select the custom page layout?

I found some posts like 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2008/07/18/how-to-customize-add-delete-or-replace-the-site-action-menu-items-in-publishing-site.aspx

and

http://www.directsharepoint.com/2011/12/creating-custom-fly-out-menu-sharepoint.html

but since I am quite new at this, I have tried editing directly the siteaction.xml file directly and added the code

```
<ConsoleNode Action="cms:CreateNewPublishingPageAction" DisplayText="cms,siteactions_createpage_displaytext" Description="cms,siteactions_createpage_description" HideIfDisabled="true" UseResourceFile="true" MenuGroupId="100" Sequence="6000" IsSiteRelative="true" PermissionContext="CurrentList" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/crtpage.gif" NavigateUrl="../_layouts/Createcreatepage.aspx" ID="wsaCreatePage1" />
```

but didn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your link and just want to add it to Site Action menu, you can use [CustomActions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms460194.aspx).
 To do this you need an empty sharepoint project with empty element. in element.xml file you can add this lines:

```
<CustomAction
Id="YOUR_CUSTOM_ID"
GroupId="SiteActions"
Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
Sequence="1001"
Title="YOUR_MENU_TITLE"
Description="YOUR_MENU_DESCRIPTION"    
>
<UrlAction Url="YOUR_URL"/>
```

You can find more about Locations and GroupIds [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb802730.aspx).